Error converting file to pdf No office manager available after 30000 millisec
When I am sending multiple requests to convert to PDF I am getting No office manager available after 30000 millisec exception.
Any help will be appreciated.
I tried 2 solutions below, but it was not working:
jodconverter:
  local:
    enabled: true
    task-execution-timeout: 120000  # Increase timeout to 120 seconds

LocalOfficeManager.builder()
    .taskExecutionTimeout(120000L)  // Set timeout to 120 seconds
    .build();


Where is the remote, headless OpenOffice/LibreOffice instance running?
